# How to do function like func()()()()()()

Tags: c#

So, I want to do some function, like this - func()()()()....()(), so that you can infinitly add this round brackets or you can add just 2 or 3, or whatever.

I tried return the same function that executes, but in c# it seems doesn't work, maybe no.

```
private static Action BigMethod(bool stopped=false)
{
    if(stopped == true) return null;

    return BigMethod(stopped);
}
```

But it obviously doesn't work, so could you help me with this riddle?

Thanks a lot for taking your time!

Comment: Why not call the method in a loop?

Comment: recursive function ?

Comment: What's the point of doing this?

Comment: You can't do this with the built in delegates, but you can define your own. `delegate F F(); F Method() => Method; Method()()()()()...;`

Comment: You need a Y-combinator: `public delegate T S<T>(S<T> s); public static T U<T>(S<T> s) => s(s); public static Func<A, Z> Y<A, Z>(Func<Func<A, Z>, Func<A, Z>> f) => U<Func<A, Z>>(r => a => f(U(r))(a)); var example = Y<int, int>(f => x => x < 10 ? f(x + 1) : x); Console.WriteLine(example(3));`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - can only speak for myself, but I marked it as unclear, because I fail to understand why someone would need/want this (and sadly OP is unresponsive)

Comment: @RandRandom I think that the OP gave it away by calling their question "riddle". It's probably pure curiosity, that serves no practical purpose.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - you could be absolutly correct, though it could be lost in translation and "riddle" is a failed attempt to translate "question" | https://translate.google.com/?sl=ru&tl=en&text=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0&op=translate

Comment: @Enigmativity there isn't point, I just wanted to know how this can be implemented in c#, that's it.

Because in python for example you could just do thing like this:

def func(stop=false):
   if(stop==true):
        return

   return func

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that the compiler can understand what `func()()()()` will do at compile time, you need a method that returns a delegate, which returns a delegate, which returns ...

You can't achieve this with the built in `Action` or `Func<>` delegates. But you can define your own delegate type which returns itself;

```cs
delegate Riddle Riddle();
Riddle Method() {
    if (something)
        return null;
    return Method;
}
Method()()()()()()...()()();
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I didn't know that you can make delegate that return itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible with infinite parentheses. If you are OK with a finite number of parentheses, the function below gives the answer to the ultimate question of life the universe and everything, if you invoke it with 13 parentheses:

```
static Func<Func<Func<Func<Func<Func<Func<Func<Func<Func<Func<Action>>>>>>>>>>> Riddle()
{
    return () => () => () => () => () => () => () => () => () => () => () => () => Console.WriteLine(42);
}
```

Usage example:

```
Riddle()()()()()()()()()()()()();
```

Comment: Oh, Theo. I had so much respect... ;-)

Comment: I mean in python you could easily do this, 
def func(stop=False):
     if(stop==True): 
         return; 
return func;

Maybe, with this example from python it will be more clear.
Thank you!

Comment: @ВладЕрстенюк unfortunately I don't know Python!

Comment: @ВладЕрстенюк C# is a statically typed language so the return type must be fixed, unlike Python where you can return anything because it's dynamically typed

Answer (score 0):

You might need a Y-combinator:

```
public delegate T S<T>(S<T> s);

public static T U<T>(S<T> s) =>
    s(s);

public static Func<A, Z> Y<A, Z>(Func<Func<A, Z>, Func<A, Z>> f) =>
    U<Func<A, Z>>(r => a => f(U(r))(a));

var example = Y<int, int>(f => x => x < 10 ? f(x + 1) : x);
Console.WriteLine(example(3));
```

This prints `10`.

You might be able to get this to do what you want. It's a self defining, recursive function.

At some point in my life I'd like to know how a delegate that passes itself in can generate a recursive function like this. It might require psychedelics.